# Disable logged_in filter for precise URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am quite new to Rails, so please let me know if I don't use the correct terms.

I am trying to create a website that lets people create their own elections. The latest version of the website is available [here](http://spo2tu.be:8001/).

People creating the elections have to register. The elections are only viewable and editable by logged in members (You don't want anyone to be able to see your election).

For this reason, I have this at the beginning of my election controller :

```
class ElectionsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :logged_in?
```

Logged in users access the elections via this kind of url : http://spo2tu.be:8001/elections/:id

The person creating the election defines a list of voters that will have to vote for a candidate.
What happens is that for each voter, a unique url is generated and sent by mail. The URL are of form : http://spo2tu.be:8001/elections/:id/votes/:long_generated_id

**Example** : http://spo2tu.be:8001/elections/1/votes/Y2_8TDL8Hkpz2MzzV_bpgw

My issue is that due to the heritage of the before_filter, non logged_in users see an error when reaching this URL .

The error is the following :

```
undefined method `elections' for nil:NilClass

@election = current_user.elections.find(params[:election_id])
```

What I think happens is that since the election has a logged_in before filter, it is impossible to get a reference to it in a deeper URL.

Since those URLs are unique, temporary and generated, I would like to let the persons having access to them also access the elections; hence bypassing the before_filter.

What would be the proper way to achieve this? 
One possible solution I see would be to avoid nesting and change the URL to be of kind http://spo2tu.be:8001/votes/Y2_8TDL8Hkpz2MzzV_bpgw directly, but that wouldn't solve the issue since voters still need to have access to the election to see the description.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after the suggestion from Ramon Gebben, the problem comes indeed from this line :

```
@election = current_user.elections.find(params[:election_id])
```

Since users are not logged_in, **current_user** is not defined, which lead to the error.

Changing this line to

```
@election = Election.find(params[:election_id])
```

solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify for with method you want to check if the user is logged in.

so change `before_filter :logged_in?` to `before_filter :logged_in?, only: [:edit, :new, :destroy]`

And you are probably using [this method](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) of logging in.
And this depends on a session being present for current_user method to work.

So I suggest you don't use this to look it up but you use a params in url to specify which user is trying to access the election.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: But that would let anyone view elections in this case, not only people that know the correct vote URL. This is a behavior I want to avoid.